# How do I store a clicked list item in a session with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

My goal is to store the `alert` message in the session. How can I accomplish this?

**JavaScript**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("ul[id*=licity] li").click(function(){

         alert($(this).text());
     });
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="licity">                   
    <li><a href="#">Satara</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Karad</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Wai</a></li>                   
</ul>
```

Comment: Then learn JavaScript.

Comment: Are you talking about the HTML5 `app.manifest`?

Comment: No.  I am just talking about simple html and cs coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make localstorage in javascript as :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("ul[id*=licity] li").click(function(){
    localStorage.setItem('livalue',$(this).text());
 });
});
```

if u want to use session storage then :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("ul[id*=licity] li").click(function(){
    sessionStorage.setItem("livalue", $(this).text());
 });
});
```

For more details on sessionstorage : **https://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/**

**localStorage and sessionStorage both extend Storage. There is no difference between them except for the intended "non-persistence" of sessionStorage,localstorage is better because When the window or tab is permanently closed, any data stored through sessionStorage is deleted.**

Comment: op needs to store in session

Comment: localStorage doesn't have anything to do with session

Comment: @Unknownman - It's obvious that JavaScript doesn't have sessions. Local storage (or cookies) is the closest you can get.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Could be [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)?

Comment: @MartinDulak- localStorage and sessionStorage both extend Storage. There is no difference between them except for the intended "non-persistence" of sessionStorage.localstorage is better because When the window or tab is permanently closed, any data stored through sessionStorage is deleted

Comment: The sessionStorage object is equal to the localStorage object, except that it stores the data for only one session. The data is deleted when the user closes the browser window.  localStorage object stores the data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year.

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla - I totally understand but you can't tell the one is better. They are different concepts and sometimes you don't want data to persist. And the question was about session.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following things to keep values

1. [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)
2. [localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)
3. [Server session](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) (shared as php session)
4. [JS variable](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp) (if you want to use only for current instance of website), store in simple variable

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/

Or in short you use methods: `setItem()` and `getItem()` of globally available object `sessionStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ali_rafiq/pPt2A/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#licity li").click(function(){

     alert($(this).text());
 });
 });
```

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to accomplish? It's the same as the OP's code, just with a changed selector.