# Save div order in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, local-storage

I'm using the Shapeshift jQuery plugin http://mcpants.github.io/jquery.shapeshift/ which was pretty easy to set up and use. But now I want to be able to save the div order in local storage so that the next time browser is started the div order does not change.
I'm absolutely new to localstorage (like I started reading about it a few hours ago) and I can't seem to figure it out. Please help me.

Comment: do you have a code sample?

Comment: just read my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969006/how-do-i-store-a-clicked-list-item-in-a-session-with-javascript/24969030#24969030 it will help u...

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla Thanks. So using local storage can I even save left and margin top values? Then how can I retrieve them afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localStorage is just a key value pair actually can be used as :

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

if u want to save div order in it then :

```
localStorage.setItem("divorder", "//value of div order//");
```

if u want to store margin values store them as :

```
localStorage.setItem("marginval", "// margin values //");
```

You can retrieve the values from localStorage and store them in variables or as you want :

```
var margin = localStorage.getItem("marginval");
var divord = localStorage.getItem("divorder");
```

where **marginval** and **divorder** are just keys storing your values.

Comment: hope @user3716080 above explanation is enough for you...if you need more help then comment...

Comment: Thx. I'm slowly getting it. let's say I have two divs having same class both of which can be dragged around. Finally they both will have a particular value of left or right or both. How can I save those values automaically and when the page reloads the two div get to the same position where they were left before.

Comment: @user3716080 as per your question.... i answered very correctly and with full details ,if you have a problem somewhere just post a question and we will answer... the scenerio which you are describing above cannot be solved unless we have some code etc ... so if my above answer helps you then upvote accept it otherwise not..Thank you...

Comment: @user3716080-just make a simple small scenario of your question and post it and we will try to solve in a best possible manner..Thank you..